# Esterel Compiling in Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, compiling, 32-bit, gcc, binary

The latest version of esterel is available only in 32 bit. Installed it in 64 bit ubuntu. When compiling esterl to C. I haven't get any errors.

```
esterel -simul foo.strl

cc -c foo.c
```

While running:

```
xes foo.o
```

geeting

> "i386 architecture of input file foo.o is incompatible with
>   i386:x86-64 output"

Tried `cc -c -m32 foo.c` also still the same error. How could be this fixed?

Comment: How did you install `esterel` I could find a working package in the web , many links are broken? Anyway, this is a quick shot. Make full compile with linking by removing `-c` flag. Try `cc -o foo foo.c` instead then `xes foo`